# HuggingFace Accelerate won't use the proper number of processes

Tags: huggingface

The server I'm using has a total of 4 GPUs and I want to use 2. I'm therefore trying to do `accelerate launch --num_processes 2 train.py`, but when I run the script it says that the number of processes is only 1. Why is this happening? It seems as of now I can either only use all 4 or only 1.

Comment: Have you tried using `accelerate config`?

Comment: I haven't tried using a separate config file, but would that be necessary? The documentation seems to make it clear that passing `--num_processes` should be enough.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/basic_tutorials/launch#why-you-should-always-use-accelerate-config), in your case it might be that you also need to pass `--multi_gpu` where `accelerate config` would handle everything for you

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci I haven't used `accelerate config` yet, but it seems that `--multi_gpu` along with `--num_processes` works. Interesting.

Comment: I'll add an answer to your post for future readers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the command line interface, you also need to pass the `--multi_gpu` argument to enable distributed training.
However the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/basic_tutorials/launch#why-you-should-always-use-accelerate-config) recommends using `accelerate config` to facilitate the configuration.

Comment: Yeah I figured this out as well, thanks for the answer. I find it a little counterintuitive that `--multi_gpu` wouldn't be set to True whenever the number of processes is larger than 1 though.